# Нужно получить верное значение PHP Foreach

Tags: php, массивы, foreach

В конце массива мне возвращает значение $_POST['cat_id'] последнее число, к примеру title - 6 (из 6), когда внутри массива $_POST['cat_id'] он выводит верно:
title - 1,
title - 2,
title - 3, ... title - 6.   Как дописать массив чтобы получать именно нужное значение в зависимости от title (к примеру 1 или 4) ?

````
$categories = array();
?>
<select name="cat_id" class="form" placeholder="Категория">
<?php foreach($categories as $cat)
{
    ?>
    <option value="<?php $_POST['cat_id'] = $cat['id']; ?>"><?php echo $cat['title'];?>
<?php echo $_POST['cat_id'];?></option>
    <?php
  }
?>
</select>
<br><?php echo $_POST['cat_id'];?><br>```
````

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: рискну предплоложить, что вы пытаетесьсделать что-то вроде `$selected = $_POST['cat_id'] == $cat['id'] ? "selected" : "";` и `<option value="<?= $cat['id']?>" <?= $selected ?>><?= $cat['title']?></option>`